# InverseBooleanConverter is missing

Tags: c#, xaml

I have checked out an XAML application from a repository and am trying to build it. I got the error:

```
The tag 'InverseBooleanConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr- ...
```

I don't have experience with Universal form applications, but found that `InverseBooleanConverter` is related to the `FreshEssentials` package. I have installed this package for my current project, but this did not solve the problem.

Content of XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Tools.TestTool.Common;component/Styles/ModulesStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Have you added <xmlns:converters="namespace of converters" /> ?

Comment: or xmlns:fe="clr-namespace:FreshEssentials;assembly=FreshEssentials"

Comment: Take a look at the xmlns definition for the converter namespace. This will tell you where it's looking for that converter. These errors usually occur becuase the converter's assembly isn't built yet. Take a look at the solution's build order, and try to rebuild the offending assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error means that whatever url you've specified as `converters` in your XAML ( eg. `xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MeLibrary.Converters` ) does not contain class named `InverseBooleanConverter` which derives from `IValueConverter`.

To fix this, just point out your `converters` to correct namespace in the project. If you do not have any `InverseBooleanConverter` class, create one and point to `converters` to newly created namespace.

---

*example converter:*

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            bool testValue = (bool)value;
            return !testValue; // or do whatever you need with this boolean
        }
        catch { return true; } // or false
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
}
```